# this values in derived classes in C++

Tags: c++, inheritance, this, derived

I have a question regarding what "this" points in derived classes in C++.

```
class A
{
    int a;
public:
    void funca() { cout << this << endl; }
};
class B
{
    int b;
public:
    void funcb() { cout << this << endl; }
};
class Derived : public A, public B {};

int main() {
    Derived d;
    d.funca();
    d.funcb();  // prints 4bytes more than the above.
}
```

In this case, how are "this" in base classes interpreted in the derived class?
Is it this of the derived class or this of the base class??
From the output, I think this points to the class object where it is used. Am I right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**how are "this" in base classes interpreted in the derived class?**

I guess the question should be **How base classes resides in derived classes**

When a class is inherited by another, the compiler kind of places the members of base class in the derived class. The `this` always refers to the actual object, you are right about this. `d.funcb();` prints 2 bytes ahead because, members of `B` starts after 4 bytes of `A` in `Derived`. This 4 bytes is taken by `A::a` member variable. But the layout and memory model is not guaranteed, and varies depending on compiler. One possible memory layout for `Derived` may be

```
Members of A (4 byte in this case for a)
Members of B (4 byte in this case for b)
Members of Derived (if any)
```

So derived class does not have a *Base class "this"*, there is only one `this`, which refer to the actual object. And derived classes get copy of base class members in them.

Comment: This just gets much more complex when you involved multiple and virtual inheritance, making the this pointer have different values in different types

Answer (score 0):

Class Derived contains two subobjects A and B. These subobjects have non-static member functions. The first implicit argument of these functions is the poinetr that points to the corresponding object.
So in your example when function funca is called it gets the pointer that points to subobject A inside class Derived. The same way when function funcb is called it gets the pointer that points to subobject B inside class Derived.

Shotly speaking in each class definition this denotes an object of the defined class. In the class definition of class A this denotes an object of class A. In the class definition of class B this denotes an object of class B. Inside class Derived subobjects A and B have different locations i.e. different addresses. So the output in your example will differ.